# Slide down and slide up div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code to open and close a div ( slide up/down ) using js

I have the slide down event attached to a button and the slide up event sttached to close text.

What I want is the button onclick to open and onclick again close the slide element.

Here is the JS

```
// slide down effect

$(function(){
$('.grabPromo').click(function(){
var parent = $(this).parents('.promo');
$(parent).find('.slideDown').slideDown();
});
$('.closeSlide').click(function(){
var parent = $(this).parents('.promo');
$(parent).find('.slideDown').slideUp();
});
});
```

The HTML:

```
<span class="grabPromo">Open</span>
```

and in the slide down area i have

```
<a class="closeSlide">Close</a>
```

Any help appreciated.

Ideally I want a down pointing arrow on the slide down button and a up pointing arrow to replace it to slide up on same button. And do away with the close link altogether.

Any help appreciated. Cheers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try this. it allows multiple items so isn't ID specific. and supports any content loaded via AJAX as well.   [jsfiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/UezUj/1/)

```
<div class='toggle_parent'>
  <div class='toggleHolder'>
    <span class='toggler'>Open</span>
    <span class-'toggler' style='display:none;'>Close</span>
  </div>
  <div class='toggled_content' style='display:none;'>
      My Content
  </div>
</div>
```

and

```
$('.toggler').live('click',function(){
  $(this).parent().children().toggle();  //swaps the display:none between the two spans
  $(this).parent().parent().find('.toggled_content').slideToggle();  //swap the display of the main content with slide action

});
```

Answer (score 14):

You can just use [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) in the click function:

```
$('.grabPromo').click(function(e){
    $('.slideDown').slideToggle();
});
```

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/Sd8rh/)

Answer (score 6):

```
<div id="content">
bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla blabla bla blabla bla bla
</div>
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="Slide down ↓"/>

$("#myButton").toggle(function(){
    $("#content").slideDown();
    $(this).val("Slide up ↑");
},function(){
    $("#content").slideUp();
    $(this).val("Slide down ↓")
});
```

**Online demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/amosrivera/AYWku/

**Demo with** `span`: http://jsfiddle.net/amosrivera/AYWku/1/

Comment: This would be fine , but I dont want to use input buttons. We are using <span class="grabPromo">Grab This Deal</span>

Comment: @amosrivera, haha nice arrow symbol.

Comment: @422, it doesn't matter what the click element is, he gave you the functionality, you can change the input to a span if you want, it just needs to have the same id....

Comment: @Nick hehe thanks, i like those, they are simple and work. @422 as nick said the functionality does not rely on the element type, but i added a link width the span so you see the little difference.

Comment: Thats cool, but we have other sliders on the page. So what would be the economical (code) way of adding this effect to other div buttons , as you are using ID, i dont want all buttons openeing at same time lol.

Comment: use the same toggle logic, with the parent traversing you were doing.

Comment: Here is @amosrivera demo that can be used for more than one item per page. http://jsfiddle.net/AYWku/7/

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class='parent_row'>
   <span class='toggler_row'>click here</span>
   <div class='child_row' style='display:none;'>
      Row 1
   </div>
   <div class='child_row' style='display:none;'>
      Row 2
   </div>
   <div class='child_row' style='display:none;'>
      Row 3
   </div>
</div>
```

JS/Jquery :

```
$('.toggler_row').live('click',function(){
   $(this).parent().parent().find('.child_row').slideToggle();
});
```

jQuery **.live()** has been removed in version 1.9 onwards, if it is breaking then try below scripts it will work.

```
$('body').on('click', '.toggler_row',function(){
   $(this).parent().parent().find('.child_row').slideToggle();
});
```