# JavaScript Sliding Billboard (No Flash)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ads, slidedown, google-ad-manager

I need to create a sliding billboard ad (just like the one on this website http://www.mlive.com/slidingbillboard/). I would prefer to use jQuery over Flash, for reasons I'm sure most understand. I've been Googling and haven't found a solution. In the end this will be thrown into Google Ad Manager to track click throughs. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Note: This will go at the top of the site above all content.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Slide down and slide up div on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279733/slide-down-and-slide-up-div-on-click)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily implemented in jQuery

Look here

http://jsfiddle.net/ppumkin/ArRFy/2/

apply a few styles, hover effect.. and 'tadaaa' no flash or UI.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at jQuery Effects?  You can do things like animate cssProperties (i.e. background color, size, etc), you can slide in/out.  You can fade in/out among many other operations.  you mentioned jQuery already so this might be what you are looking for:

http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/