# Sliding in and out div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a div that appears on the click of the button. However, I'm unsure how to make it slide in and out, rather than just appear.

Here is the example of where it's been used, click the first project card on the left. [maxmizemedia.co.uk](http://maximizemedia.co.uk/#)

```js
document.getElementById('project-1').addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector('.side-modal').style.display = "flex";
});

document.querySelector('.close-side-modal').addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector('.side-modal').style.display = "none";
});
```

Here is the code I'm currently using to display and hide the div.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279733/slide-down-and-slide-up-div-on-click

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE].  Also please read: [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys. I'll take a look into this now.

Comment: If you want to to actual sliding, you could place the element offscreen and then slowly change its position with JS. Or you could 'fake' sliding by using a simple css transition on the width, height or scale so that the modal is too thin to see at first, and then expands. The css approach is easier to code, but might not be as visually appealing.

Comment: Do you know if there are any tutorials for the javascript option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic mock-up of what i believe you are trying to achieve rather than using `display:none;` and `display:flex;` i've added a simple class toggle in Javascript and used the css `transition` property to control the slide animation.

```js
const item = document.querySelectorAll('.container-item');
const sidebar = document.querySelectorAll('.slide-modal');

item.forEach((i)=>{
  i.addEventListener('click',()=>{
  sidebar.forEach((s)=>{
    s.classList.remove('slide-modal--active');
  })
    var modalClicked = i.dataset.modal;
    var element = document.querySelectorAll("[data-modal='"+ modalClicked +"']")[1]
    element.classList.toggle('slide-modal--active');
  });
})
```

```css
.container{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
.container-item{
  flex-basis:50%;
  height:25vw;
  background:rgb(240,240,240);
  margin:0 10px
}

.slide-modal{
  position:fixed;
  width:25vw;
  height:100vw;
  background:rgb(200,200,200);
  right:0;
  top:0;
  transform:translateX(25vw);
  visibility:hidden;
  transition:.8s ease;
}
.slide-modal:nth-child(2){
background:rgb(150,150,150);
}
.slide-modal--active{
  transform:translateX(0);
  visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  
  <div data-modal='1' class='container-item'></div>
  <div data-modal='2' class='container-item'></div>
</div>
  
  <div data-modal='1' class='slide-modal'>
    
  </div>

  <div data-modal='2' class='slide-modal'>
    
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi Aaron, Is there a way to combine the code you've created with mine included above? I'm new to javascript and don't know how I'd apply the following to my original code.